# Snapping two line shapefiles according to attribute field value using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, snapping

I have a two line shapefiles (Trace.shp and Snap.shp). There is a GIS_ID field in both files.  Now I want to snap "Snap.shp" to "Trace.shp" according to GIS_ID value. I have tried to use Snap tool for ArcGIS Desktop but I am not sure about the results because using that solution I am not sure that line is snapped to the right line from another layer with the same GIS_ID. I want to do that using ArcGIS 10.4

Comment: Are you using [Snap tool under editing toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm)? I would try to select the same GIS_ID in both feature classes and run snap tool. You should be able to do this by joining them and iterate feature selection in ModelBuilder, or by using arcpy.

Comment: @BERA Yes,  I am using Snap tool under editing toolbox. Could you give me more details about that solution and add it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arcpy to iterate over each ID, create feature layers with the same ID's and then snap together lines which share the same id. Change inputs, field name, and snapping options and then execute in python window of ArcMap. Backup your data Before you try it.

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Or a folder with shapefiles
fc_to_snap = 'Roads2' #If shapefile, add .shp
fc_to_snap_to = 'Roads' #If shapefile, add .shp

idfield = 'Roadname' #Change to match the name of your ID field. The name and field type must be the same in both feature classes.

all_ids = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_to_snap,idfield)})

for unique_id in all_ids:
    sql = """{0}='{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc_to_snap, idfield), unique_id) #If your ID field is not a string, remove the single quotes surrounding {1}
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc_to_snap, out_layer='tosnaplyr',where_clause=sql)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc_to_snap_to, out_layer='tosnaptolyr', where_clause=sql)
    if arcpy.GetCount_management(in_rows='tosnaplyr').getOutput(0) > 0 and arcpy.GetCount_management(in_rows='tosnaptolyr').getOutput(0) > 0:
        arcpy.Snap_edit(in_features='tosnaplyr', snap_environment=[['tosnaptolyr',"END","100 Meters"]])
```

[image]

Comment: But I have a 2000 lines. How to do that with this number of lines?

Comment: I have about 2000 lines,  but when I run a script I get a couple of new layers and after that get the error message.

Comment: ERROR999999: Error executing function

Comment: An invalif SQL statement was used

Comment: It is string. Should it be integer?

Comment: Sorry.  Now I see that in one layer it is "double"  but in another one it is string.

Comment: Now that works. Great!  Will let you know when I finish.

Comment: This works until one moment. After that my ArcGIS is turned off. What could be a problem?

Comment: I dont know. Try executing the code outside ArcMap, for example in IDLE (In my start menu located under ArcGIS - Python 2.7)

Comment: Will definitely try. And again,  what I will get as a results when script stop working?  And also what I need to do next with files after script do what should do?

Comment: Up until the crash probably lines snapped correctly. I dont know what you want to do next